# Create form with javascript and ajax call in submit

Tags: javascript

I have a small problem in my ajax call, I will explain:

I have a page (article.php) where there a  that will look for items by date and company, I made a call to an ajax page "action / SearchArticle.php" which returns me the result and I the poster on my page article.php.

In the results, i have a button modified, when I click I create another  in a popup with Javascript with the columns to change and there is my problem: I want when I click submit in this popup I make a ajax call to a PHP page to amend section but it does not work.

Here's how I did

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#result #modifier').click(function () {
        // récuperer le id article
        var popINC = $(this).attr('rel');
        // récuperer commentaire article
        var popComment = $("#result #comment" + popINC).text();
        //créer le commentaire
        var comment = '<label for="comment">Commentaire</label><input type="text" id ="comment" name="comment" value="' + popComment + '"/>';
        //créer une checkbox pour id_article
        var inpInc = "<input type='checkbox' id='flag' name='flag[]' value='" + popINC + "'>" + popINC;
        //construire le formulaire avec le id_article et commentaire
        var contenu = '<form action="" method="post" id="changeFlag"><ul><li>' + inpInc + '</li><li>' + comment + '</li><button type="submit">Chercher</button></ul></form>';
        // Afficher popup
        $('#' + popID).html(contenu).fadeIn().css({
            'width': Number(popWidth)
        });
        var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 80) / 2;
        var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;
        $('#' + popID).css({
            'margin-top': -popMargTop,
            'margin-left': -popMargLeft
        });
        $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); //Ajout du fond opaque noir
        //Apparition du fond - .css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}) pour corriger les bogues de IE
        // Cacher la page HTML
        $('#fade').css({
            'filter': 'alpha(opacity=80)'
        }).fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
    $('a.close, #fade').live('click', function () { //Au clic sur le bouton ou sur le calque...
        $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function () {
            $('#fade, a.close').remove(); //...ils disparaissent ensemble
        });
        return false;
    });
    // Quand je clique sur mon formulaire modifier article crée dans la 1er partie
    $("#changeFlag").submit(function () {
        var dataString = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../action/test.php",
            dataType: 'html',
            data: dataString,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    alert('dede');
                } else {
                    $("#result").text("Errodr");
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
 });
```

The result: when I click on submit the popup page refreshes and then I have nothing!

Thank you in advance

Comment: In the console set it to persist errors across page navigation and see what JavaScript errors are there.

Comment: FYI: LIve is deprecated in 1.7+ and removed in 1.9+, stop using it.

Comment: The selector `$('#result #modifier')` is poor, just use `$('#modifier')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, the submit event handler is registered before the `changeFlag` form is created. So you need to change the submit event registration to use event delegation model.

If using jquery < 1.7 use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$("#changeFlag").live('submit', function () {
    var dataString = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../action/test.php",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: dataString,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response) {
                alert('dede');
            } else {
                $("#result").text("Errodr");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

If jQuery >= 1.7 use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('submit', '#changeFlag', function() {
    var dataString = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "../action/test.php",
                dataType : 'html',
                data : dataString,
                success : function(response) {
                    if (response) {
                        alert('dede');
                    } else {
                        $("#result").text("Errodr");
                    }
                }
            });
    return false;
});
```